# Using WLAN Router without creating new subnet

Tags: subnet, wireless-networking

I have the following network configuration at home

[image]

I'm connected through a [NanoStation M5](http://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanostationm/) to the internet. The NanoStation has a DHCP server and provides IP addresses for all wired PCs which are connected through a NetGear GS724t switch.

Now I like to have a wireless network too and the situation at home requires it that the network printer is connected directly to the WLAN router. The router is an [ASUS RT-AC66U](http://www.asus.com/de/Networking/RTAC66U/) with the latest DD-RWT firmware.

**Question:** Is it possible that the WLAN-router just forwards the local network provided by the NanoStation, so that computers connected wireless or through a wire are in the same subnet as PC1-PC4 are?

The wire from the switch is connected to the WAN port of the the WLAN router and I have tried several settings of *DHCP Forwarder* etc, without success. Can someone explain, what I have to do in detail or maybe there are some how-to's.

Comment: Disconnect the WAN port of the router and connect a LAN port. In essence, you need to use the wireless router as a bridge, not a router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disconnect the WAN port on the router from the switch and connect a LAN port on the router to the switch so that you're using the router as a bridge instead of using it as a router.

There are some further settings you need to adjust, like disabling DHCP, etc., but you should find all required information in [this DD-WRT tutorial](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point).

Comment: So in essence I want a setting [like this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) only that the first router is my NanoStation?

Comment: That looks about right. The second router would be acting as an access point rather than a router.

Comment: Indeed, connecting the cable of the switch to a normal LAN port of the router was the solution. I saw now that I can configure the WAN port as normal LAN port, but you gave me the important clue. Thanks very much.